# How to handle images especially background images in android

Tags: android, image, user-interface

I want to know how to handle images in android. How I am able to put image with correct dimensions. What is the resolution of images?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) regarding screen sizes.

From a base image size, there is a 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio in drawable size by DPI.

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size // means 1.0x here 
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

For example, 100x100px image on a MDPI will be the same size of a 200x200px on a XHDPI screen.

You can see the different size for different resolations here :

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Comment: Is there any sample app ?

Comment: @AliAshraf i don't know what you mean sample app but all of android standard app's used this method .

Comment: sample app means is there any open source app available for developers for practical knowledge but anyways thanks for your quick and considerable answer.

Comment: @AliAshraf i prefer generate your images for your app using `dimensions` in my **answer**.you can resize images by any program like `Photoshop`  or another one . you don't need any open source code for understanding this simple thing and I'm glad i could help u . if this answer is ok pls accept it . thanks